# Jest unit test for typescript files in a module or namespace

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

I am getting involved in a mvc.net project that use typescript as frontend.
There are many typescript files that are wrapped with `module Foo {...}`, where
Foo is the main module or namespace.

All the typescript files are transpile to one file `Foo.js`.
The issue is none of the typescript files have `export module Foo{...}` to export the namespace.
I want to write a unit test for this, and I have chosen Jest framework.

How can I import objects in my typescript files in my test.

package.json

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "name": "Foo-Web",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/bootstrap": "4.1.2",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.16",
    ... bunch of other libraries
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "isolatedModules": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2017"
    ],
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "outFile": "Out/dist/Foo.js",
    "removeComments": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "**/bower_components/*",
    "**/node_modules/*",
    "**/dist/*"
  ],
}
```

jest.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    "testMatch": [
        "**/__tests__/**/*.+(ts|tsx|js)",
        "**/?(*.)+(spec|test).+(ts|tsx|js)"
    ],
    "transform": {
        "^.+\\.(ts|tsx)$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": ['js', 'jsx', 'ts', 'tsx']
}
```

Format of typescript files are like

```
module Foo {
    interface blablabla ....

    export class hahaha{
     ... class implementation
    }
}
```

Test file:

```
...
var ct = new Foo.SomeClass(testProp)
....
```

Running jest test, I receive:

> Foo is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Works for me. BTW:

> The internal 'module' syntax is deprecated, use the 'namespace' keyword instead.

`index.ts`:

```js
export module Foo {
  export class SomeClass {
    constructor(private prop) {}
  }
}
```

`index.test.ts`:

```js
import { Foo } from './';

describe('63957901', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    const testProp = {};
    const ct = new Foo.SomeClass(testProp);
    expect(ct).toBeInstanceOf(Foo.SomeClass);
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/63957901/index.test.ts (10.923s)
  63957901
    ✓ should pass (4ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        12.401s
```